# multiple dynamic arrays inside a struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, dynamic-arrays

i am trying do dynamicly allocate a matrix which is inside a struct, also if anyone can also tell me how to send it to the function so i don't have to declare my struct variable globally i would really apreciate it, cuz i can't seem to figure it out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct matrice_dinamica{
    int linii, coloane;
    int **matrice;
};
struct matrice_dinamica* v = NULL;

void comanda_L_citire_matrice(int i)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &v[i].linii, &v[i].coloane);

    int v[i].(*matrice)[v[i].coloane] = malloc (sizeof(int[v[i].linii][v[i].coloane]));

    for(int x = 0; x < v[i].linii; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < v[i].coloane; y++){
            scanf("%d", &v[i].matrice[x][y]);
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    
    v = (struct matrice_dinamica*)malloc(sizeof(struct matrice_dinamica));
```

there are more things in the main function so i only gave what i thought usefull cuz the error i get is in the function
the error i get is error: expected expression before '.' token

Comment: You dereference the pointer `matrix` which is uninitialized. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: i tried using this syntax i found on here "int(*matrix)[y] = malloc (sizeof(int[x][y])); " but addapt it to my needs, when i alloc it with double pointers it works but my teacher told me it's not really that efficient so i am trying to chance my code this way

Comment: I meant to write matrice, the error is the same tho even if i correct that

Comment: It may make more sense to replace `int i` with `struct matrice_dinamica *m`, and replace `v[i].` with `m->`. Call `comanda_L_citire_matrice(&v[0])` to fill in `v[0]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't see anything wrong with `sizeof(int[v[i].linii][v[i].coloane])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid double pointers, `int **matrice` cannot be used because that is a double pointer. The storage for the matrix can be "flattened" into a single dimension and the positions of the elements for each (row,column) coordinate can calculated arithmetically as `row * num_columns + column`. For example:

```
struct matrice_dinamica{
    int linii, coloane;
    int *matrice;  // flattened
};
```

```
// Get pointer to start of a row
int *matrice_row(struct matrice_dinamica *m, int x)
{
    return m->matrice + x * m->coloane;
}

// Get pointer to an element
int *matrice_elp(struct matrice_dinamica *m, int x, int y)
{
    return matrice_row(m, x) + y;
}

// Get value of an element
int matrice_el(struct matrice_dinamica *m, int x, int y)
{
    return *matrice_elp(m, x, y);
}

// Store value in an element
void matrice_el_store(struct matrice_dinamica *m, int x, int y, int val)
{
    *matrice_elp(m, x, y) = val;
}

void comanda_L_citire_matrice(struct matrice_dinamica *m)
{
    int *md;

    scanf("%d %d", &m->linii, &m->coloane);

    m->matrice = malloc(m->linii * m->coloane * sizeof(int));

    md = m->matrice;
    for(int x = 0; x < m->linii; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < m->coloane; y++){
            scanf("%d", md++);
        }
    }
}
```